# Optimal way to compute permutations in julia

Tags: algorithm, julia, combinatorics

Consider a list `[1,1,1,...,1,0,0,...,0]` (an arbitrary list of zeros and ones). We want the whole possible permutations in this array, there'll be `binomial(l,k)` permutations (`l` stands for the length of the list and `k` for the number of ones in the list).

Right now, I have tested three different algorithms  to generate the whole possible permutations, one that uses a recurrent function, one that calculates 
the permutations via calculating the interval number `[1,...,1,0,0,...,0]`
to `[0,0,...0,1,1,...,1]` (since this can be seen as a binary number interval), and one that calculates the permutations using lexicographic order.

So far, the first two approaches fail in performance when the permutations are
approx. 32. The lexicographic technique works still pretty nice (only a few miliseconds to finish).

My question is, specifically for julia, which is the best way to calculate
permutations as I described earlier? I don't know too much in combinatorics, but I think a descent benchmark would be to generate all permutations from the total `binomial(l,l/2)`

Comment: The "best way" will depend upon the constraints of your problem (what is the maximum size of the list?  are the values of `l` and `k` uniformly distributed?) and what you consider to be best (simplest, fastest, or most straight-forward? optimized for total memory used or for CPU time?).  It also sounds like you already have a pretty good solution.  Why are you not satisfied?

Comment: Actually the values of `k` and `l` are arbitrary. The inspiration is a physical system composed by fermions. It happens that an appropriate mathematical basis to describe it is the (Fock basis)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_state], that has dimension `binomial(l,k)` and a member of the basis is some permutation of the list with zeros and ones that I gave. If I recall correctly, a good case would be one in which `l>>k`, the idea is to have an enough big basis in order to simulate a decent physical system (In fortran, I did something like `~10^4` basis dimension once more or less fast).

Comment: On the other hand, I would like that the algorithm is fast enough to generate the whole basis, and if possible, to save as much as memory used. The last inspiration is to learn new combinatorial algorithms and to dig in this direction, that I want to really explore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have mentioned yourself in the comments, the case where `l >> k` is definitely desired. When this is the case, we can substantially improve performance by not handling vectors of length `l` until we really need them, and instead handle a list of indexes of the ones.

In the [RAM-model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), the following algorithm will let you iterate over all the combinations in space `O(k^2)`, and time `O(k^2 * binom(l,k))`

Note however, that every time you generate a bit-vector from an index combination, you incur an overhead of `O(l)`, in which you will also have the lower-bound (for all combinations) of `Omega(l*binom(l,k))`, and the memory usage grows to `Omega(l+k^2)`.

#### The algorithm

```
"""
Produces all `k`-combinations of integers in `1:l` with prefix `current`, in a
lexicographical order.

# Arguments
- `current`: The current combination
- `l`: The parent set size
- `k`: The target combination size
"""
function combination_producer(l, k, current)
    if k == length(current)
        produce(current)
    else
        j = (length(current) > 0) ? (last(current)+1) : 1
        for i=j:l
            combination_producer(l, k, [current, i])
        end
    end
end

"""
Produces all combinations of size `k` from `1:l` in a lexicographical order
"""
function combination_producer(l,k)
    combination_producer(l,k, [])
end
```

#### Example

You can then iterate over all the combinations as follows:

```
for c in @task(combination_producer(l, k))
    # do something with c
end
```

Notice how this algorithm is *resumable*: You can stop the iteration whenever you want, and continue again:

```
iter = @task(combination_producer(5, 3))
for c in iter
    println(c)
    if c[1] == 2
        break
    end
end

println("took a short break")

for c in iter
    println(c)
end
```

This produces the following output:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,4]
[1,2,5]
[1,3,4]
[1,3,5]
[1,4,5]
[2,3,4]
took a short break
[2,3,5]
[2,4,5]
[3,4,5]
```

If you want to get a bit-vector out of `c` then you can do e.g.

```
function combination_to_bitvector(l, c)
    result = zeros(l)
    result[c] = 1
    result
end
```

where `l` is the desired length of the bit-vector.

Comment: This implementation no longer seems to work (testing in Julia 1.1). In particular, `produce` was deprecated some time ago, and I'm not aware of how it was replaced. Could you update this answer for at least Julia 1.0?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll: for the task of generating all combinations: see `combinations` in the package `Combinatorics`.