# Given n, generate all permutations of size lesser than 0.5n

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, julia, permutation

Given an integer number `n`, I would like to generate into a vector, as efficiently as possible, all the permutations of integers of size lesser or equal than `0.5n`.

For instance for `n=7` that would be:

```
15-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [2, 1]
 [2, 3]
 [3, 1]
 [3, 2]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 3, 2]
 [2, 1, 3]
 [2, 3, 1]
 [3, 1, 2]
 [3, 2, 1]
```

My current idea is to generate all permutations of size `k` lesser than `0.5n` and appending them:

```
using Combinatorics

function generate_half_perm(n)
    half_n = floor(Int, n/2)
    result = []
    for l in 1:half_n
            for c in permutations(1:half_n, l)
                    push!(result, c)
            end
    end
    return result
end
```

generate_half_perm(7) then gives the first instance of this post. I think this code is currently above `O(2^(n/2).n)` which is the complexity of the code without the one needed to generate the combinations, `combinations(1:half_n, l)`.

I was wondering if there was any better idea which may lead to a faster code given that my
n will likely be above 100.

I had the idea of using [this code [Optimal way to compute permutations in Julia]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771435/10094437) but produce function is deprecated and should be replaced according with this [other answer [How to replace consume and produce with channels]](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-replace-consume-and-produce-with-channels/5125/4) and now that starts to become complicated for me to understand!

If you have a better idea algorithmically, without the Julia implementation, I'll be glad to try it :)

small edit: I realize that what I wanted was:

```
collect(Iterators.flatten(permutations.(powerset(1:7,0, floor(Int, 7/2)))))
```

Thanks to @Przemyslaw Szufel for made me find it :)

Comment: For n=100 there are far, far, too many of these to store in all the memory on earth. If n=100, there are ~ 3e64 size n/2 ones.

Comment: @dmuir, yes you are right! I will run my project as far as I can and never reach 100 then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your value "half of N" equal to 3 this would be:

```
using Combinatorics
Iterators.flatten(permutations.(powerset(1:3,1)))
```

Note that this is non-allocating so if you want to see the result `collect` is required:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.flatten(permutations.(powerset(1:3,1))))
15-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [1, 2]
 [2, 1]
 [1, 3]
 [3, 1]
 [2, 3]
 [3, 2]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 3, 2]
 [2, 1, 3]
 [2, 3, 1]
 [3, 1, 2]
 [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would have taken a long time to find out if not never :)

Comment: Alright, I realize what I wanted was: ```collect(Iterators.flatten(permutations.(powerset(1:7,0, floor(Int, 7/2)))))``` (that's actually what is asked in first paragraph but badly describe in the instance and code) but you made me find it with your answer so I'm not going to edit my question nor untick your answer, many thanks again :)

Comment: This command will also generate an empty set `[]`. Should you want to avoid it give `1` as the starting value rather than zero.